# Macro or formula to APPEND (not create a new column) a cell''s (entire column) content to another

Tags: excel, macros

Trying to create a macro or find a solution to be able to append the content from all rows in Column K to the end of all the rows in Column S, respectively. Creating a new column does not help me.

I need to be able to APPEND the data from Column K to Column S (every month). Any help is appreciated. Both these columns are on the same sheet.

Comment: So, without formulas, you need to take `K1` and add that to the end of `S1`? Will there be a space in between (or anything)?

Comment: Also you say that creating a column doesn't help - do you mean you *can't* use a helper column, or couldn't figure out how to do so?

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Try this sub:

```
Sub AppendColumns()
  Dim sheetname As String, srccell as String, dstcell as String
  Dim src As Range, dst As Range
  Dim y As Integer

    sheetname = "Sheet1" 'Put your sheet´s name here, as listed in VBA file list
    srccell = "K1" 'Put your source top cell here
    dstcell = "S1" 'Put your destination top cell here

    Set src = Worksheets(sheetname).Range(srccell) 
    Set dst = Worksheets(sheetname).Range(dstcell)         
    y = 0
    Do Until src.Offset(y, 0) = ""
        dst.Offset(y, 0) = dst.Offset(y, 0) & src.Offset(y, 0)
        y = y + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```